# Jquery ajax warns "Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread..."

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm loading html content using JQuery $.ajax and it gives warning

Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

here is my code

```
var html = $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://localhost/loginmodal.php",
    async: false
}).responseText;

$('#' + divID).append(html).trigger("create");
```

I found somewhere that this warning can be fixed if I use async: true option.
But, when I use async: true option, ajax simply doesn't work. If I use async: false option, it gives the error.

Situation.

1. globalFunctions.js has the utility function which calls above code. This function has the only code above, nothing else. It has a parameter divID on which ajax html will be loaded.
2. home.php has a button. If user clicks the button, this calls the function in globalFunctions.js.

This is it! 
The only library I'm using is JQuery.

Thank you for your answer in advanced!

Answer (score 0):

As the error says the problem is the `async: false` setting, which forces an synchronous ajax request.

The proper way to handler ajax request is to make use of callback method like

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://localhost/loginmodal.php"
}).done(function (html) {
    $('#' + divID).append(html).trigger("create");
});
```

- [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Comment: I changed code to yours but it gives same warning. Thanks to you, I read and understood what asynchronous call is, which is ajax 'A'. It's simply like multi-thread behavior. Anyway, I think your code has no problem but I don't understand why my code still gives same warning.

Answer (score 0):

remove the async: false in your ajax call

```
       async: false
```